# The quote isnt appearing on the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

What I'm trying to do is when the button is click the quote appears on the webpage but its not working. I am using a api

```js
$(".btn").on("click",function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({cache:false})
  $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&callback=",function(data){
   $(".quote").html(data[0].content + "-" + data[0].title);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class = "container-fluid">
  <div class = "row"></div>
  <div class = "text-center quote-box">
    <h1 >Random Quote Generator</h1>
    <p class = "quote"> Click the button to get a random quote</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class = col-md-4 id = quote-button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id = quote-button>New Quote</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id = quote-button><i class = "fa fa-twitter">Twitter</i></button>
  </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working in my machine

Comment: In what order did you write your code? First jQuery, then HTML (like in here) or differently?

Answer (score 1):

Change `http` to `https`. Issue might be due to **"Mixed Content"**, `http` and `https` which will be blocked by your browser.

```
  $(".btn").on("click",function(){
   $.ajaxSetup({cache:false})
   $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&callback=",function(data){
    $(".quote").html(data[0].content + "-" + data[0].title);
  });
});
```

Check this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/bfMY2HNm99uTuMjvt77U?p=preview)

> **Mixed conten**t occurs when initial `HTML` is loaded over a secure `HTTPS`
>   connection, but other resources (such as images, videos, stylesheets,
>   scripts) are loaded over an insecure HTTP connection. This is called
>   mixed content because both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` content are being loaded to
>   display the same page, and the initial request was secure over `HTTPS`.
>   Modern browsers display warnings about this type of content to
>   indicate to the user that this page contains insecure resources.

Answer (score 0):

The request is working but the browser is blocking it because it is a cross origin request. Either get the server administrator has to enable cors or check if a JSONP request is supported.